# Java, List only subdirectories from a directory, not files

Tags: java, file

In Java, How do I list only subdirectories from a directory?

I'd like to use the java.io.File functionality, what is the best method in Java for doing this?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

You can use the [File](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class to list the directories.

```
File file = new File("/path/to/directory");
String[] directories = file.list(new FilenameFilter() {
  @Override
  public boolean accept(File current, String name) {
    return new File(current, name).isDirectory();
  }
});
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(directories));
```

**Update**

Comment from the author on this post wanted a faster way, great discussion here: 
[How to retrieve a list of directories QUICKLY in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034977/how-to-retrieve-a-list-of-directories-quickly-in-java)

Basically:

1. If you control the file structure, I would try to avoid getting into that situation.
2. In Java NIO.2, you can use the directories function to return an iterator to allow for greater scaling. The directory stream class is an object that you can use to iterate over the entries in a directory.

Comment: hi, thank for reply. But I don't have to iterate over the all items in a directory. I have to directly list the subdirectory from the directory. B'coz I have lots of files and only few subdirectory in a directory so, checking isDirectory() is time consuming. please reply me another way.

Comment: I updated my post, in particular, take a look at Jon Skeet comment on the question. And the NIO response since Java NIO 2 has an iterator for the directories function that returns a stream of directories.

Comment: What Skeet comment are you referring to? What is the better performing answer here?

Answer (score 132):

A very simple Java 8 solution:

```
File[] directories = new File("/your/path/").listFiles(File::isDirectory);
```

It's equivalent to using a FileFilter (works with older Java as well):

```
File[] directories = new File("/your/path/").listFiles(new FileFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        return file.isDirectory();
    }
});
```

Comment: How does the double colon `::` work in this instance?

Comment: I noticed that no other answer uses FileFilter so I added the equivalent version without using method references. For more about method references, refer to this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001427/double-colon-operator-in-java-8) or this [article](http://www.speakingcs.com/2014/08/method-references-in-java-8.html).

Comment: does this get subdirectories or just the directories directly under /your/path/ ?

Comment: @amadain no recursion as expected https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles()

Comment: :: sends the function isDirectory from class File as a parameter

Answer (score 14):

@Mohamed Mansour you were almost there... the "dir" argument from that you were using is actually the curent path, so it will always return true. In order to see if the child is a subdirectory or not you need to test that child.

```
File file = new File("/path/to/directory");
String[] directories = file.list(new FilenameFilter() {
  @Override
  public boolean accept(File current, String name) {
    return new File(current, name).isDirectory();
  }
});
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(directories));
```

Answer (score 8):

In case you're interested in a solution using Java 7 and NIO.2, it could go like this:

```
private static class DirectoriesFilter implements Filter<Path> {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(Path entry) throws IOException {
        return Files.isDirectory(entry);
    }
}

try (DirectoryStream<Path> ds = Files.newDirectoryStream(FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(root), new DirectoriesFilter())) {
        for (Path p : ds) {
            System.out.println(p.getFileName());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

> I'd like to use the java.io.File functionality,

In 2012 (date of the question) yes, not today.  `java.nio` API has to be favored for such requirements.

Terrible with so many answers, but not the simple way that I would use that is `Files.walk().filter().collect()`.

Globally two approaches are possible :

1)`Files.walk(Path start, )` has no `maxDepth` limitations while

2)`Files.walk(Path start, int maxDepth, FileVisitOption... options)` allows to set it.

Without specifying any depth limitation, it would give :

```
Path directory = Paths.get("/foo/bar");

try {
    List<Path> directories =
            Files.walk(directory)
                 .filter(Files::isDirectory)
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
} catch (IOException e) {
    // process exception
}
```

And if for legacy reasons, you need to get a List of `File` you can just add a `map(Path::toFile)` operation before the collect :

```
Path directory = Paths.get("/foo/bar");

try {
    List<File> directories =
            Files.walk(directory)
                 .filter(Files::isDirectory)
                 .map(Path::toFile)
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
} catch (IOException e) {
    // process exception
}
```

Comment: There is also ```Files.list(Path)``` which is probably the same as ```Files.walk(Path,1)```.

Comment: @David L Indeed `Files.list(Path)` is a fair alternative if we don't want to iterate recursively folders. To iterate folders recursively, `walk()` fits better.

Answer (score 3):

```java
ArrayList<File> directories = new ArrayList<File>(
    Arrays.asList(
        new File("your/path/").listFiles(File::isDirectory)
    )
);
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! Can you elaborate on your answer a little bit? Like explaining interesting parts of your code snippets or linking to the documentation for futher reading?

Comment: This should be the correct answer as it provides a File object with the complete Canonical Path.

This might be old but it's worth pointing this out

Answer (score 3):

This will literally list (that is, print) all subdirectories. It basically is a loop kind of where you don’t need to store the items in between to a list. This is what one most likely needs, so I leave it here.

```java
Path directory = Paths.get("D:\\directory\\to\\list");

Files.walk(directory, 1).filter(entry -> !entry.equals(directory))
    .filter(Files::isDirectory).forEach(subdirectory ->
{
    // do whatever you want with the subdirectories
    System.out.println(subdirectory.getFileName());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

For those also interested in Java 7 and NIO, there is an alternative solution to [@voo's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17629043/4289700). We can use a *try-with-resources* that calls `Files.find()` and a lambda function that is used to filter the directories.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Stream;


final Path directory = Paths.get("/path/to/folder");

try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.find(directory, Integer.MAX_VALUE, (path, attributes) -> attributes.isDirectory())) {
    paths.forEach(System.out::println);
} catch (IOException e) {
    ...
}
```

We can even filter directories by name by changing the lambda function:

```
(path, attributes) -> attributes.isDirectory() && path.toString().contains("test")
```

or by date:

```
final long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
final long yesterday = new Date(now - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000L).getTime();

// modified in the last 24 hours
(path, attributes) -> attributes.isDirectory() && attributes.lastModifiedTime().toMillis() > yesterday
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    File files = new File("src");
    // src is folder name...
    //This will return the list of the subDirectories
    List<File> subDirectories = Arrays.stream(files.listFiles()).filter(File::isDirectory).collect(Collectors.toList());
// this will print all the sub directories
Arrays.stream(files.listFiles()).filter(File::isDirectory).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a starting directory as a `String`

1. Create a method that takes a `String` path as the parameter.  In the method:
2. Create a new [File](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) object based on the starting directory
3. Get an array of files in the current directory using the `listFiles` method
4. Loop over the array of files

   1. If it's a file, continue looping
   2. If it's a directory, print out the name and *recurse* on this new directory path

Comment: hi, thank for reply. But I don't have to iterate over the all items in a directory. I have to directly list the subdirectory from the directory. B'coz I have lots of files and only few subdirectory in a directory so, checking isDirectory() is time consuming. please reply me another way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution for my code. I just did a litlle change [from first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5125258/8053001). This will list all folders only in desired directory line by line:

```
try {
            File file = new File("D:\\admir\\MyBookLibrary");
            String[] directories = file.list(new FilenameFilter() {
              @Override
              public boolean accept(File current, String name) {
                return new File(current, name).isDirectory();
              }
            });
            for(int i = 0;i < directories.length;i++) {
                if(directories[i] != null) {
                    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(directories[i]));

                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error!");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me, is missing from the list of answers. Hence I am posting this solution here:

```
File[]dirs = new File("/mypath/mydir/").listFiles((FileFilter)FileFilterUtils.directoryFileFilter());
```

Here I have used `org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.FileFilterUtils` from Apache commons-io-2.2.jar. Its documentation is available here: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.2/org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/FileFilterUtils.html

Comment: Can you pls avoid using third-party libraries? For sure there are some utilities doing this in less than one line of code ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JAVA 7 Files api

```
Path myDirectoryPath = Paths.get("path to my directory");
List<Path> subDirectories = Files.find(
                    myDirectoryPath ,
                    Integer.MAX_VALUE,
                    (filePath, fileAttr) -> fileAttr.isDirectory() && !filePath.equals(myDirectoryPath )
            ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you want a specific value you can call map with the value you want before collecting the data.