# How to find folders under specific fold in java?

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to find and print folder names through spring and jsp.
I want to find folders' names and how many are there under /somefolder/ folder

I want the code to be in java style, please help!

Comment: What have your tried so far? Please post your code.

Comment: you want find folders name of server root??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [File#listFiles](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) to get the files in a directory, and you can use [File#isDirectory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory%28%29) to check if those are files or directories, either by looping over the result or by using a [FileFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileFilter.html) that you pass to listFiles.

Comment: Can you post a sample code please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5125258/14955