# how to efficiently get number of subdirectories and files

Tags: android

In my little file explorer app I show the number of sub-elements in each directory like:

[image]

To set those numbers, I launch an `AsyncTask` (so the `ListView` won't get "laggy") from my `Adapter`'s `getView()` method and that for each item in the list. However, when viewing some system directories (like "/" for example) with huge number of subdirs and files, the garbage collector is going insane and performance drops significantly (multiple instances of my `AsyncTask` still stay in memory even after the app gets finished).

I'm quite sure this is related to how I implemented the subdirs and subfiles check that I'm doing inside the `AsyncTask`, but the following recursive approach is the only thing I could think of:

```
   //countHidden is a boolean indicating whether to count hidden files
   private int[] getSubFilesCount(File root) {
    int fcount = 0;
    int dcount = 0;
    File[] files = root.listFiles();
    if (files != null)
        for (File f : files) {
            if (f.isDirectory()) {
                getSubFilesCount(f);
                if (f.isHidden()) {
                    if (countHidden)
                        dcount++;
                } else {
                    dcount++;
                }
            } else {
                if (f.isHidden()) {
                    if (countHidden)
                        fcount++;
                } else {
                    fcount++;
                }
            }
        }
    int[] tcount = { fcount, dcount };
    return tcount;
}
```

**The question: is there any alternative to get the number of subdirectories and files that will work faster then the approach posted above?**

Answer (score 0):

You could do what's suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125242/list-only-subdirectory-from-directory-not-files) which is effectively the same as you're doing but slightly more succinct (if you don't mind me saying so). Obviously you'd have to do it for files and directories. I believe Java 7 provides a better way of doing this but unfortunately you're limited to Java 6 at the moment with Android.