# Java IO API: how to get into file subdirectory?

Tags: java, file-io, io, nio

I have a File pointing to a *base dir*:

```
File baseDir = new File("c:\\baseDir");
```

now I want to "go into a subdir":

```
File subDir = new File("c:\\baseDir\\subDir");
```

I only found how I can do it via strings concatenation. But is there an API function to do the job?

Comment: You might want to refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125242/java-list-only-subdirectories-from-a-directory-not-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one of the overloaded constructors serving the purpose:

```
> File(File parent, String child)

Creates a new File instance from a parent abstract pathname and a child pathname string.
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help, getAbsolutePath() return the absolute path of the sub directory, no need to append the parent path.

```
String filePath = "/home/untitled";

    File[] directories = new File(filePath).listFiles(new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File file) {
            return file.isDirectory();
        }
    });

    for (File file : directories) {
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
     File subDir = new File("c:\\baseDir","subDir");
```