# Open various files using a java netbeans program

Tags: java, file, netbeans

I would like to make a program that in java using netbeans.  I want this program to search through a specified folder and display all files into a text area.

here's what I saw on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5125258/262852):

```
File file = new File("/path/to/directory");
String[] directories = file.list(new FilenameFilter() {
  @Override
  public boolean accept(File current, String name) {
    return new File(current, name).isDirectory();
  }
});
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(directories));
```

how do I make it *better*?

Comment: so what is your problem ?

Comment: i dont know how to do it

Comment: im a bit of a noob

Comment: why, id rather not give out my email.

Comment: this website is for asking questions not a free service to get your work done by someone

Comment: way too broad.  I don't want to discourage you, but gotta vote to close.  If you break this up into smaller projects, that would make sense.  Also, you need at least SOME code.  Show at least an attempt to list the contents of a directory is my suggestion.

Comment: okay. sorry to be a pain.

Comment: If you can just show be a quick line of code that opens cmd and uses a command to open a file I can probably figure out the rest

Comment: your other question is excellent, just edit this one a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File file=new File("path to your file");   
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("RUNDLL32.EXE SHELL32.DLL,OpenAs_RunDLL " + file.getAbsolutePath());
    p.waitFor();
```

this code simply opens Files