# Java FileFilter list only directories

Tags: java

So I want to list only directories which are in a specified directory. I tried both FileFilter and FilenameFilter. Both DO NOT work for me, because they also include Files. But somehow others on SO don't have a problem w/ this.

```
java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)
```

FileFilter:

```
private static File maps_dir_src = new File("./maps/");
private static File[] maps_arr_src = maps_dir_src.listFiles(new FileFilter() {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        return file.isDirectory() && !file.getName().toLowerCase().equals("lobby");
    }
});
```

FilenameFilter:

```
private static File maps_dir_src = new File("./maps/");
private static File[] maps_arr_src = maps_dir_src.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File file, String name) {
        return file.isDirectory() && !name.toLowerCase().equals("lobby");
    }
});
```

Any tips?

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your answers @everybody

Somehow when I created a MCVE it worked. But the original code was still in need of a fix. After some time trying different ways, I found a working way. (Don't know why it works like that and didn't work before.)

```
private static File maps_dir_src = new File("./maps/");
private static File[] maps_arr_src = maps_dir_src.listFiles(new FileFilter() {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        return file.isDirectory() && !file.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("lobby");
    }
});
```

**EDIT:** Somehow this fix only works on macos but not on windows :/

Answer (score 1):

Your code for FileFilter looks valid; for FilenameFilter you need this:

```
return new File(file, name).isDirectory();
```

Can you also try examples from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125242/java-list-only-subdirectories-from-a-directory-not-files)?

Answer (score 1):

From `isDirectory()` docs:

> Where it is required to distinguish an I/O exception from the case that the file is not a directory, or where several attributes of the same file are required at the same time, then the Files.readAttributes method may be used.

Could you try the `readAttributes` method? Maybe you'll get some IO exception that'll clarify the problem.