# copy most recent file placed in drectory using gradle

Tags: gradle

So I have a bunch of archives in a directory that look like this:

test_61995.zip
test_61234.zip
test_61233.zip

I want to copy only the latest file from here using Gradle. Is is possilbe to sort the files and date and time and copy usng gradle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can do that. Here is an example

Kotlin DSL:

```
tasks {
    val cp by creating(Copy::class.java) {
        from(File("/home/madhead/Downloads/").listFiles().sortedBy { it.lastModified() }.last())
        into(File("/home/madhead/Downloads/so53777253/"))
    }
}
```

Groovy DSL:

```
task cp(type: Copy) {
    from(new File("/home/madhead/Downloads/").listFiles().sort{ it.lastModified() }[0])
    into(new File("/home/madhead/Downloads/so53777253/"))
}
```

This will copy the latest modified file from `/home/madhead/Downloads/` to `/home/madhead/Downloads/so53777253/`.

Comment: thanks but it is not working. Got the below error

build file 'D:\test\gradle\build.gradle': 10: unexpected token: : @ line 10,
 column 29.
         val cp by creating(Copy:: class.java) {
                                 ^

Comment: Are you using Kotlin DSL or Groovy?

Comment: I am using Groovy.

Comment: So that's the reason you get "unexpected token"

Comment: So is it not possible in groovy?

Comment: It is possible in Groovy

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked but the .reverse() should be removed for latest file  else it takes the oldest file

Comment: That may be. I didn't tested Groovy version :). Edited the answer.

Comment: Can you please let me know how can we copy the latest directory as well?

Comment: Use [`.listFiles(File::isDirectory)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27940412/750510).