# Most efficient/fastest way to get a single file from a directory

Tags: python, file, directory

What is the most efficient and fastest way to get a single file from a directory using Python?

More details on my specific problem:
I have a directory containing a lot of pregenerated files, and I just want to pick a random one. Since I know that there's no really efficient way of picking a random file from a directory other than listing all the files first, my files are generated with an already random name, thus they are already randomly sorted, and I just need to pick the first file from the folder.

So my question is: how can I pick the first file from my folder, without having to load the whole list of files from the directory (nor having the OS to do that, my optimal goal would be  to force the OS to just return me a single file and then stop!).

Note: I have a lot of files in my directory, hence why I would like to avoid listing all the files to just pick one.

Note2: each file is only picked once, then deleted to ensure that only new files are picked the next time (thus ensuring some kind of randomness).

**SOLUTION**

I finally chose to use an index file that will store:

- the index of the current file to be picked (eg: 1 for file1.ext, 2 for file2.ext, etc..)
- the index of the last file generated (eg: 1999 for file1999.ext)

Of course, this means that my files are not generated with a random name anymore, but using a deterministic incrementable pattern (eg: "file%s.ext" % ID)

Thus I have a near constant time for my two main operations:

- Accessing the next file in the folder
- Counting the number of files that are left (so that I can generate new files in a background thread when needed).

This is a specific solution for my problem, for more generic solutions, please read the accepted answer.

Also you might be interested into these two other solutions I've found to optimize the access of files and directory walking using Python:

- [os.walk optimized](http://blog.fraggod.net/2010/12/oslistdir-and-oswalk-in-python-without-lists-by-the-grace-of-c-api-generator-and-recursion-custom-stack)
- [Python FAM (File Alteration Monitor)](http://python-fam.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Figure it out once, then set up your own kind of database to make it quicker?

Comment: Directories are *not* sorted. Rather, they list items in the current directory structure order (on-disk structure), which *could* be the creation order.

Comment: I avoided using DBMS for a reason, because I don't need any indexation of any sort. I don't want to pick a specific file, just any file, and only a single one.

@Martijn: what I said was a simplification to better convey my idea. Files are sorted by inode, but that's not the point here: I just want to get the first file because my files are already random so I don't have to care about randomly picking a file: picking just any file in this directory will already give me a random result.

Comment: im not even sure the os can get a file by given name from a directory without internally listing the files in the directory.

Comment: @Lucasmus: hence my question :/

Comment: @user1121352: no, `os.listdir()` calls return a reasonably stable listing, not a random one, if the directory contents do not change.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: This is true, but not in my case: every file is only accessed once, then deleted. Thus, everytime I will access the directory, only new files will be available. The randomness is thus preserved.

Comment: POSIX specific solution is to use `opendir()`/`readdir()` system functions via `ctypes`.

Comment: @user1121352: That part was not listed in your question, and is *enormously* important to the answers. Moreover, this probably means you *do not have many files* in your directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when creating the files add the name of the newest file to a list stored in a text file. When you want to read/process/delete a file:

1. Open the text file
2. Set filename to the name on the top of the list.
3. Delete the name from the top of the list
4. Close the text file
5. Process filename.

Comment: Nice solution. In fact, this is the best one given the description I gave of my problem. We can also enhance it: at file generation append new names at the end of the file instead of the top (avoid opening and reading the whole file), and at file access just read the first line and remove it from the text file (I'm sure there are ways to do that without having to read the whole file too). I mark this solution as the accepted answer, although the solution [given by Lucasmus is also pretty clever](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13378514/1121352).

Comment: In my final solution, I will implement another variant of the indexing concept: I won't generate the names randomly but using a deterministic pattern with an increasing numbering (eg: file1.ext, file2.ext, file3.ext, etc.). Then I will keep an index file that will store 2 fields: the current ID (eg: 1 for file1.ext), and the last ID of the latest generated file (eg: 1999 for file1999.ext). This has several advantages: the index file is always very short; I can always access directly a new file; and lastly I can also count the number of files left without listing the files

Comment: by computing latestID - currentID, which allows me to run a background thread that generates new files as we run under a specified threshold. In the end, we get an almost constant access time for these two operations: accessing a file and counting the number of files left. Con is that I must be careful about concurrent accesses to the index file and the generated files to avoid unsynchronization (as a failguard, I can just regenerate it when I encounter an exception with a try: except: block).

Answer (score 2):

Don't have a lot of pregenerated files in 1 directory. Divide them over subdirectories if more than 'n' files in the directory.

Comment: This is not a solution: I would still have to list all the folders, and then list all the files in the subdirectory I will access to know how many pregenerated files are still left to choose to either delete the folder or not. If I don't do that, in the long run I will get a lot of empty folders, which I will still walk and waste CPU cycles.

Comment: Not true. Listing the folders will take not too much time, because only n folders to list. Then you descend from folder into folder until you find a file. After use you delete the file and check if folder is empty. If so delete the folder. Do this recursively and you will drastically reduce amount of files listed. (What I meant is you divide the files over the folders recursively, so folders can contain subfolders as well.) This will reduce the files you list from O(N) to O(n-root(N)) if I'm correct.

Comment: ok I get your point. In fact, if we stretch the idea to its maximum, it's a kind of recursive algorithm, but for file placement instead of data processing: to maximize its potential, we can put every file in its own folder (so one file per folder!) and every 2 folders are recursively placed inside one folder. This way, we would create a tree, of log2(N) number of levers (the root being N/2**log2(N)). The complexity would be something like O(n*log2(N)) but we have to use the Master Theorem to get more precise. (continued in the next comment)

Comment: This would indeed be the fastest way to access directly a file without any sort of caching, but there's a big limitation: filesystems generally accepts a limited depth of folders recursion, thus this system cannot really work directly on a filesystem. Thus, we should virtualize the folders hierarchy in our own application, but then we can also use some kind of caching, and then in this case there are other better ways to access a single file by example by using an index just like DBMSes.

Comment: This does not fully answer the question, but is a very nice idea. I'll keep it in my books.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `random.choice()` on the `os.listdir()` result:

```
import random
import os

randomfilename = random.choice(os.listdir(path_to_directory))
```

`os.listdir()` returns results in the ordering given by the OS. Using random filenames does not change that ordering, only adding items to or removing items from the directory can influence that ordering.

If your fear that you'll have too many files, do not use a single directory. Instead, set up a tree of directories with pre-generated names, pick one of those at random, then pick a file from there.

Comment: As I said, my files are already randomly generated, so there's no need to use random.choice().

Also, your solution still list all the files in the directory, which will be awfully slow if I have a huge number of files (which is my case).

Comment: @user1121352: Using random filenames *does not create a random order*.

Comment: I know that, but random filenames + deleting a file after the first access generates a random order. It's a kind of twisted [sampling without replacement](http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/parker/sampling/repl.htm)